# Java JSP Filtering on Query String

Tags: java, jsp, filter

I have a webpage I am currently building for an internal work tool. It is a sample website that allows a user to login and then execute query from the database. I just implemented a filter to re-direct not-logged in users to the login page. The doFilter function looks like this

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

    if (session == null || session.getAttribute("user") == null) {
        // No logged-in user found, so redirect to login page.
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/Login.jsp"); 
    } else {
        // Logged-in user found, so just continue request.
        chain.doFilter(req, res); 
    }
}
```

In my web.xml I have

```
<filter>
<filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>Servlets.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/Home.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

If I access Home.jsp directly it will re-direct to the Login Page. However, once logged in, the user is moved to the Home.jsp page which allows the user to execute a query against the database. The home URL will look like

http://localhost:8084/LiveTrades/Home.jsp

But once they provide input, it will move to a new page displaying the results with url string like

http://localhost:8084/LiveTrades/Request?BIC=cat (assuming the user entered 'cat' for the input 'BIC' field).

If a user inputs this above url directly when not logged not, it will process fine, when it shouldnt. I know this is because my filter is only being invoked from the Home.jsp page. How can I get around this to prevent pages with Request* to be filtered?

Would it be easier to have another jsp page, say Results.jsp, and have the Servlet that processes the information from the database pass the data on to Results.jsp? Then I can simply add Results.jsp to the web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by re-structuring my webpage. The results are now displayed via a JSP page, the data is passed to the JSP page from a Servlet. Now in my filter I simply add the Result JSP page and problem solved.